# In a windows batch file, getting "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Tags: batch-file

I want to use the current time as the title of an output file, like this:

```
set NAME=%TIME%
```

Then I want to write to the file, like this:

```
echo words >> %NAME%
```

However, when I try to do so, it gives this error:

> *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` in the current time is causing the problem. To remove the `:` from the filename, replace it with `-` or some other valid filename character as follows.

```
set NAME = %TIME::=-%
```

Will give a filename like below (Time is `10:14 AM` when I ran this on my `test.bat` file.

```
10-14-12.44
```

Answer (score 2):

The time likely has colons in it, e.g., 10:58:31.  Colons are invalid characters for filenames on Windows.

### EDIT:

Here's a [routine](http://kawishsiddiqui.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/batch-get_timestamp-function/) I've used before for timestamps.  Just copy the GET_TIMESTAMP logic to your bat file, and then call it with a format (e.g., MM-DD-YYYY) and an output variable of your choice (e.g., TODAY).

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :GET_TIMESTAMP MM-DD-YYYY TODAY
echo %TODAY%
goto END

rem ========================================================
rem == http://kawishsiddiqui.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/batch-get_timestamp-function/
rem ========================================================
:GET_TIMESTAMP fmtString vResult
  set RepFormat=%1
  set MShortMap=01-Jan;02-Feb;03-Mar;04-Apr;05-May;06-Jun;07-Jul;08-Aug;09-Sep;10-Oct;11-Nov;12-Dec
  set MLongMap=01-January;02-February;03-March;04-April;05-May;06-June;07-July;08-August;09-September;10-October;11-November;12-December
  set DShortMap=01-Mon;02-Tue;03-Wed;04-Thu;05-Fri;06-Sat;07-Sun
  set DLongMap=01-Monday;02-Tuesday;03-Wednessday;04-Thursday;05-Friday;06-Saturday;07-Sunday
  set DShort2LongMap=Mon-Monday;Tue-Tuesday;Wed-Wednessday;Thu-Thursday;Fri-Friday;Sat-Saturday;Sun-Sunday
  :: a) Parse the date (e.g., Fri 02/08/2008)
        set cur_yyyy=%date:~10,4%
        set cur_yy=%date:~12,2%
        set cur_mm=%date:~4,2%
        set cur_dd=%date:~7,2%
        set cur_ddd=%date:~0,3%
  :: b) Parse the time (e.g., 11:17:13.49)
        set cur_hh=%time:~0,2%
        if %cur_hh% lss 10 (set cur_hh=0%time:~1,1%)
        set cur_nn=%time:~3,2%
        set cur_ss=%time:~6,2%
        set cur_ms=%time:~9,2%
  ::
  call set cur_mmm=%%MShortMap:*%cur_mm%-=%%
       set cur_mmm=%cur_mmm:;=&rem.%
  ::
  call set cur_mmmm=%%MLongMap:*%cur_mm%-=%%
       set cur_mmmm=%cur_mmmm:;=&rem.%
  ::
  call set cur_dddd=%%DShort2LongMap:*%cur_ddd%-=%%
       set cur_dddd=%cur_dddd:;=&rem.%
  ::
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:B= %%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:C=,%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:YYYY=%cur_yyyy%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:MMMM=%cur_mmmm%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:MMM=%cur_mmm%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:DDDD=%cur_dddd%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:DDD=%cur_ddd%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:YY=%cur_yy%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:MM=%cur_mm%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:DD=%cur_dd%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:HH=%cur_hh%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:MI=%cur_nn%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:SS=%cur_ss%%%
  call set RepFormat=%%RepFormat:MS=%cur_ms%%%
  set "%~2=%RepFormat%"
exit /b

:END
endlocal
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Any tips on removing colons from the time? I'm not sure how to do that in a batch file.